# Is it possible to have a google form confirmation message that displays part of the response data?

Tags: google-apps-script, form-submit, google-forms

I am setting up a google form for an upcoming auction. As bidders arrive at the auction, we will have them fill out a basic google form (i.e. name, address, ID) and a a 'Bidder ID' is auto generated based on the row number in the response spreadsheet.

What I would like to happen is once the form is submitted, the confirmation message includes their 'Bidder ID'. The spreadsheet is setup to put the Bidder ID in Column J. Is this possible at all?
Please let me know if more information is required.

Many thanks.
Ben

Comment: It's now possible, look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037987/accessing-user-entered-data-upon-submit-in-google-forms

Answer (score 3):

No it's not possible.  There is no way to add dynamic data to the custom confirmation message after submitting a Google Form. You can change the message in the the confirmation page, but you can't retrieve and concatenate anything into that confirmation message.

You would need to convert everything to a stand alone HTML App for something like that.