# Accessing user entered data upon submit in google forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-forms

I have a google-form that has the following two fields:

- Email address: - A text box
- Tool: - A radio button

  - Tool 1
  - Tool 2
  - Tool 3

The user would enter his email address and select a tool and click submit. I would like the following message to appear:

> Thanks for responding. An email has been sent to you to at *entered email address* to download *selected tool*.

I have the following piece of code in the script editor

```
    function emailFormSubmission() {
        var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();//the current form
        var dest_id = form.getDestinationId(); //the destination spreadsheet where form responses are stored
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dest_id);//open that spreadsheet
        var theFormSheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; //read the first sheet in that spreadsheet
        var row = theFormSheet.getLastRow(); //get the last row
        var emailid = theFormSheet.getRange(row,2,1,1).getValue();//get column 2 corresponding to the email id. column 1 is timestamp. so, skip that.
        var tool = theFormSheet.getRange(row,3,1,1).getValue();//get column 3 corresponding to the selected tool.
        form.setConfirmationMessage('Thanks for responding. An email has been sent to you '+ emailid + ' to download' + tool);
    }
```

I have also set the `triggers` to be Run -> `emailFormSubmission`, Events -> `from Form` , `onFormSubmit`.

What happens is: Suppose the first user ('A') enters his information and clicks submit. His entered information gets displayed correctly. When second user ('B') enters his information and clicks submit, A's information is displayed. When third user ('C') enters his information and clicks submit, then B's information is displayed. I found that the issue is with "getlastrow()" since the spreadsheet is updated *after* emailFormSubmission is processed.

Whats wrong with the above code? How do I fix this?

**UPDATE**

Based on @wchiquito's comments, I changed the code to following to make it work.

```
function emailFormSubmission(e) {
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    //Check this link on how to access form response:
    //https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events?hl=en

    var responses = e.response;//e is of type formresponse.
    var emailid = responses.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
    var tool = responses.getItemResponses()[1].getResponse();
    Logger.log(emailid);
    Logger.log(tool);
    form.setConfirmationMessage('Thanks for responding. An email has been sent to  '+ emailid + '   with instructions to download ' + tool +'. If you do not find our email in your inbox, please check your spam folder');  
    Logger.log(form.getConfirmationMessage());
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it still sets the confirmation message for the next submission, not the current one. So if A submitted the form, then B submits it, B gets A's response.

Comment: emailFormSubmission, is this function depleted? I think now it is `onFormSubmit()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remember that the event `On form submit` ([Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events)) receives a parameter that has the following structure:

- values​​
- range
- namedValues​​

and you can do something like:

```js
function emailFormSubmission(e) {
    ...
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    ...
}
```

Try the following code to observe the structure of the parameter `e`:

```js
function emailFormSubmission(e) {
    ...
    Logger.log(e);
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

First, excuse my confusion, I showed you the structure of a `Spreadsheet form submit event` when you really are using a `Form submit event`.

Sure enough, a `Form submit event` has the following structure:

- response

Returning an object of type [`FormResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response).

Therefore, defining the event: `On submit form` (`Form submit event`), you can do something like the following:

```js
function emailFormSubmission(e) {
  var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  for (var i = 0, len = itemResponses.length; i < len; ++i) {
    Logger.log('Response #%s to the question "%s" was "%s"',
               (i + 1).toString(),
               itemResponses[i].getItem().getTitle(),
               itemResponses[i].getResponse());
  }
}
```

However, the confirmation message set according to the data sent as responses of the form, does not seem very clear, you can set the message, but will not display for the active response, if not for the next.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this did not help. I get `e` to be `undefined` when I log it. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @Bhushan: When sending a response from the Form get `undefined` in the parameter `e`? Do not run the function directly from the code editor, from there if you get `undefined` for the parameter `e`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am a beginner, so didn't know about having to test the script from the live form instead of the editor. Your code snippet helped. e is of type `FormResponse` and access to the `FormResponse` is through `e.response`as mentioned here in form submit events: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events?hl=en. Now, I have all the right information to be printed, but form.setConfirmationMessage() doesn't work as expected. On submitting, I just get a default message saying "Your response has been recorded" instead of my custom message. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your confirmation message should be changed with a line something like: `form.setConfirmationMessage('Thanks for responding. An email has been sent to you '+ e.emailid + ' to download' + e.tool);`. However you're Logging those elements (you say they print correctly), you should be using the same method of accessing those variables. If an `error` occurred when you called `form.setConfirmationMessage()` (maybe `emailid` and `tool` are no longer defined), then it will use the default message in its place - you see this happening, so an error likely occurred.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice - Thanks for the note. The issue was not with the code. I had to authenticate the script to allow it to run. The authentication expires every now and then. So, reauthenticating and running it made it work.

Comment: @wchiquito - The snippet that you have above is good. But mine is a really simple form. I just modified it to :
    `var responses = e.response;//e is of type formresponse.
    var emailid = responses.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
    var tool = responses.getItemResponses()[1].getResponse();`
I'll still mark your response as the answer.

Comment: +1 for teaching me that the Logger has string formatting... how long have I been using GAS and I didn't know that... [duh](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger).

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is these two lines right here:

```
var emailid = theFormSheet.getRange(row,2,1,1).getValue();//get column 2 corresponding to the email id. column 1 is timestamp. so, skip that.
var tool = theFormSheet.getRange(row,3,1,1).getValue();//get column 3 corresponding to the selected tool.
```

When you call `getLastRow()` on a sheet - you're getting the last row. Sure, but considering the order of events and how these values are processed, you need a `+1`, to get the most recent submission. Currently you're one row behind when your code runs to update the Form confirmation message.

So just change your code to the following:

```
var emailid = theFormSheet.getRange(row+1,2,1,1).getValue();
var tool = theFormSheet.getRange(row+1,3,1,1).getValue();
```

Spreadsheets are  the most confusing of Google services, in my opinion. When you get values in the Spreadsheet, they're returned as an `[]` or `[][]` depending on what your Range is when you call `getValues()`. But `getRange()` on a `sheet` starts at index 1 (to make it easier to read in code I suppose). Often times I find that I have an off-by-one error because of the way data is passed around. Just keep that in mind as you work with Spreadsheets :)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this did not help. The variables `emailid` and `tool` are both empty strings when I access row+1. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I'm glad that @wchiquito's answer was able to help you. Personally I don't rely on `events` from form submissions in my scripts - I need to process the data multiple times at random times so I have other parameters that I follow. I suppose I targeted my answer toward someone whose code ran *after* the form was submitted, and that processes the raw data of the response spreadsheet by getting particular ranges. I'm sorry that I kind of fell into my own little world there - I guess I just assumed you were doing it the same way as me because I didn't see `event` variables in your question :P

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: want you want can't be done with Google forms.

Explanation:
form.setConfirmationMessage() sets the confirmation message for the form as stored on the server, not for the current active form. Same applies for example for form.setTitle(). The active form will not be modified. One would expect different behaviour for the confirmation message, but alas, this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with the add-on "Formfacade".
It's free to use in 1 form.