# onSubmit event not working msg: TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined

Tags: events, google-apps-script, google-forms, gs-installable-triggers

I have a google form contain only one question 
[form layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J5bg.png)

and I would like to update the confirmation message in the onSubmit event. 
Here is my code,

```
function onsubmit1(event){  
  var activeform = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  activeform.setConfirmationMessage("Thank you "+ event.values[0]);
}
```

My deployment step is

1. save the code
2. Add Trigger (function to run: onsubmit1(), Choose which deployment should run: HEAD, Select event source: from FORM, Select event type: on form submit, Failure notification settings: notify me daily)
3. Run onsubmit1

and then
the error message shown

> TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined. (line 3, file "onsubmit")

and the deployment is failed.

[image: deployment error message]

How can I retrieve the value from the current response?

//Update
I have modified the code to

```
function onSubmit(e){
  var namevar = e.response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  form.setConfirmationMessage("Thank you"+namevar);
}
```

The function can be run with event captured.
However, as the other mentioned, confirmation message CANNOT be set in this way as namevar returned the response of last submission.

Explanation can be found in 
[how to set Confirmation Message based on form Responses in google forms using Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738404/how-to-set-confirmation-message-based-on-form-responses-in-google-forms-using-ap)

Comment: The confirmation message can't be dynamically set in this way.

Comment: @JamesD Is there anyway I can set it properly with the value of current response?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help and I find a more detail explanation on the confirmation message setting. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738404/how-to-set-confirmation-message-based-on-form-responses-in-google-forms-using-ap)

Answer (score 0):

Form Submit for scripts built in  the form rather than the  spreadsheet doesn't have a values parameter.

[Form Submit for Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1)

[Form Submit for Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: Is there a way to capture the current response?

Comment: The response is provided in the event object of the Form onFormSubmit trigger.

Comment: Thank you for that. The error message is displayed when I run the function (the run button) in the script editor. Instead, I should just save the script and test it on the form.

Comment: I'm suggesting to you that you are in the script editor for the form not the script editor for the Linked Spreadsheet.  So the onFormSubmit trigger event object that you're receiving does not contain  `event.values`.  You will only get that event object if you writing an onFormSubject script in the Linked Spreadsheet.  But I don't think that you can  set the confirmation message this way.  You have to set that up before the form is even launched.

Comment: I have the following modification in my program,
1. apply the script to the form
2. test the function directly in form instead of run the function in the script editor
3. Updated the code to [code]
var namevar = e.response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  form.setConfirmationMessage("Thank you"+namevar);

Though I cannot set the confirmation message as I expected (namevar returned the response in last submission), I am more clear in the flow. 

Thank you for your suggestion.