# Different confirmation message based on response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

My google form has only one question that asks the user to enter in a number between 1 - 10. I want the confirmation message to change depending on if the user picks a number between 1 and 4 or between 5 and 10. I am only getting the first response.

```
  function myFunction() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var choice = form.getResponses();
  var response;
  if (choice<5){
  form.setConfirmationMessage('Custom Response 1');
  } else {
  form.setConfirmationMessage('Custom Repsonse 2');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Issues:

There are **two** issues here:

- the first one has to do with your code:

  `choice` is not a value but an [array](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getresponses) of all of the form's
  responses. To get the first value of the last response, assuming your
  form has only one question you need to do that:

  `var choice_value=parseInt(choice[choice.length-1].getItemResponses()[0].getResponse());`
- The second one has to do with the `setConfirmationMessage` which is
  very well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738404/how-to-set-confirmation-message-based-on-form-responses-in-google-forms-using-ap):

  > we can't conditionally set and immediately display a custom message
  > for the current user's response based on what their answers were. The
  > confirmation message is "front-loaded" in a sense.

**Not the desired solution but closer to what you want:**

```
  function myFunction() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var choice = form.getResponses();
  var choice_value=parseInt(choice[choice.length-1].getItemResponses()[0].getResponse());
  var response;
  
  if (choice_value<5){
   response = 'Custom Response 1';
  } else {
   response = 'Custom Response 2';
  }
    
    form.setConfirmationMessage(response);
}
```

This solution won't return the correct response message after ths submission form which is not the desired behaviour. But this is the limitation of the `setConfirmationMessage` function. As far as I know, there is no way to dynamically set confirmation message based on the answer.

Comment: Thanks Marios! This really helped. I think I can make this work. It's for a game so it might actually be funnier if your choice is based on the previous person's choice.