# how can i get the last modified row in a sheet to display a value in a form response from another sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet named "Credentials" populated with the following data:

[image]

And another sheet in the same spreadsheet named "Clients" which is linked to a google form:

[image]

My goal here is to show on the confirmation message the data from the "Credentials" sheet which is in the same row as the row that is filled when a form is submitted. E.G: the form data that was stored in row 2 should show "usr a" and "pass a" on the confirmation message

I have this apps script to do so but it always shows the last data from the "Credentials" sheet on the form confirmation message and i can't see why:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet_clientes = ss.getSheetByName('Clients')
  var sheet_demos = ss.getSheetByName('Credentials')
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(ss.getFormUrl())

  
  var demosRange = sheet_demos.getRange('A2:B4')
  var demosData = demosRange.getValues()
  var lr = sheet_clientes.getLastRow()
  var user = demosData[lr][0]
  var password = demosData[lr][1]
  form.setConfirmationMessage('Congratulations: Your user is:\n' + user + '\n Your password is:\n' + password)
}
```

Comment: The form response will not fire the onEdit trigger

Comment: you can get it from the onFormsubmit trigger as e.range.rowStart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Form Submit Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) of Google Apps Script to run the script whenever a response was submitted.

But for `setConfirmationMessage(message)` [Bryan P](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22744831) explained that

> we can't conditionally set and immediately display a custom
> message for the current user's response based on what their answers
> were. The confirmation message is "front-loaded" in a sense.

Since we cannot use `setConfirmationMessage()` for this case, I created an alternative that will send the credentials to the email address the provided in the response.

### Try this:

**Code:**

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var spreadsheet = sheet.getParent();
  var credSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Credentials");
  var creds = credSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 2).getValues();
  
  var values = e.namedValues;
  var email = values['Email Address'];
  var username = creds[0][0];
  var password = creds[0][1];
  var message = 'Your user is:' + username + '\nYour password is:' + password;
  var subject = 'Credentials';
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message)
}
```

**Trigger Setup:**

1. In your Apps Script, go to the left side menu and click **Triggers**.
2. Click **Add Trigger.**
3. Copy the setup below.
4. Click **Save**

*Note: Make sure to copy and save the code provided above before creating the trigger.*

[image]

**Example:**

[image]

[image]

### References:

- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Class GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app)

Comment: @SebaRossi - In my setup above, I created the form using the spreadsheet. In your spreadsheet go to Insert -> Form, Once you finished creating your form, it will automatically create a new Sheet in your spreadsheet. It is usually named Form Responses but you can still rename it. It will instantly link the Sheet to Form. Also, the App Script should be created using spreadsheet Tools -> Script Editor for the Form Submit trigger to work as it is part of Google Sheet events.

Comment: Now i got it, thanks a lot for this response. My final goal was to actually send the response through an email, so you saved me!