# Using data from var in subjectLine

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-forms, asana

I'm modifying Amit's code ( found here: http://labnol.org/?p=20884)
to try to send email with the data from a Google Form.
But what I'm trying to grab is from his keys and columns.
I want to specifically take the first 1 and 2 column's data from the row in question and use it as a var in the subject field.
But the output (in email and when sent to asana) is listed as undefined. Where did I go wrong?

```
/*
   Send Google Form Data by Email v4.2
   Written by Amit Agarwal amit@labnol.org
   Source: http://labnol.org/?p=20884
*/

/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

function Initialize() {

  try {

    var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

    for (var i in triggers)
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);

    ScriptApp.newTrigger("EmailGoogleFormData")
      .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
      .onFormSubmit().create();

  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Please add this code in the Google Spreadsheet");
  }
}

function EmailGoogleFormData(e) {

  if (!e) {
    throw new Error("Please go the Run menu and choose Initialize");
  }

  try {

    if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) {

      // You may replace this with another email address
      var email = "x+00000000@mail.asana.com";

      // Enter your subject for Google Form email notifications

      var key, entry,
        message = "",
        ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
        cols = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

      // Iterate through the Form Fields
      for (var keys in cols) {

        key = cols[keys];
        entry = e.namedValues[key] ? e.namedValues[key].toString() : "";

        // Only include form fields that are not blank
        if ((entry !== "") && (entry.replace(/,/g, "") !== ""))
          message += key + ' :: ' + entry + "\n\n";
        var first = entry[1];
        var last = entry[2];

              var subject = first+" "+last+": Interested Candidate";

      }

      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error.toString());
  }
}

/* For support, contact developer at www.ctrlq.org */
```

Comment: For every row of data, you want to send one email?

Comment: Hi @SandyGood ! You're my hero. Yes. Every new row to the sheet sends a new email.

Comment: Found this thread. Maybe I could use it, but again, I'm lost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037987/accessing-user-entered-data-upon-submit-in-google-forms?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`entry` is a string, defined here:

```js
    entry = e.namedValues[key] ? e.namedValues[key].toString() : "";
```

...which you later treat as an array:

```js
    var first = entry[1];
    var last = entry[2];
```

At this point, `first` and `last` will both be `undefined`, because `entry` **isn't** an array. Further, this is inside a `for` loop that's traversing all the columns in the row - you can't see any bad side-effect from that, but these assignments and generation of a `subject` are happening multiple times.

That last clue suggests a better way to achieve your goal. Define the `first` and `last` variables before the loop, with default values. Then when looping over columns, watch for the columns containing the candidates' name, and update the default contents. Finally, after the loop, generate the subject line.

```js
function EmailGoogleFormData(e) {

  if (!e) {
    throw new Error("Please go the Run menu and choose Initialize");
  }

  try {

    if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) {

      // You may replace this with another email address
      var email = "x+00000000@mail.asana.com";

      // Enter your subject for Google Form email notifications

      var key, entry,
        first = "unknown", last = "unknown",
        message = "",
        ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
        cols = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

      // Iterate through the Form Fields
      for (var keys in cols) {

        key = cols[keys];
        entry = e.namedValues[key] ? e.namedValues[key].toString() : "";

        // Only include form fields that are not blank
        if ((entry !== "") && (entry.replace(/,/g, "") !== ""))
          message += key + ' :: ' + entry + "\n\n";

        if (key == "first") {  // Assumes "first" is column header
          first = entry;
        }
        if (key == "last") {  // Assumes "last" is column header
          last= entry;
        }

      }

      var subject = first+" "+last+": Interested Candidate";

      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(error.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sandy Good has created a similar app [Data Director](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-director-for-forms/bjlicikmbfbjckkgemmiddonmigijpbj?hl=en). I don't know why he did not mention it here? May be it's not what you're looking for.

I haven't used it yet, but thought his works might help someone who needs it.

### ----------------------------------------

**OVERVIEW:**

**Send form data to different sheet.  Integrate with Calendar.  Sends emails.  Makes an Edit URL and/or a PreFilled URL.**

The Data Director for Forms Add-on has multiple features.  It can send the form response to an alternate spreadsheet.  It can send an email or multiple emails when the Form is submitted.  It can add a guest to your calendar event.
     When your Google Form is submitted, the Data Director for Forms Add-on can get the last form submission, and save it to a second spreadsheet destination of your choice.  The destination spreadsheet can be any Google spreadsheet that your Google account has permission to write to.  For example: Your Google Form currently writes data to a spreadsheet, but you want the form response to also go into a second sheet in the same spreadsheet.  This Add-on can do that.  Or the Add-on can write a copy of the form response to a completely different spreadsheet.
     You should install this add-on if you want to save a copy the form response to to a destination other than what is set in the Form's design.
     But that's not all Data Director can do!  Data Director will also create an Edit URL and/or a PreFilled URL, and save those links to the spreadsheet.
    There's even more!  It will also send an email to the email address of your choice with a custom message.  This is an extra option that you may want or need to use.

Here's a list of What Data Director can do!

- Send a copy of the form response to a Google spreadsheet.

  - The same Google spreadsheet that is already receiving the Form response, or
  - A different spreadsheet than is currently receiving the Form response.
- Exclude the timestamp from the copied response if you choose.  The default is to include the timestamp.
- Create an Edit URL and save a link to the destination spreadsheet.
- Create a PreFilled URL and save the link to the destination spreadsheet.
- Send multiple emails to the email addresses of your choice.
- Send an email to the email address collected from a Form field.
- Include the Edit Url and/or the PreFilled Url in the email.

  - CC the email to the address of your choice, or not.
  - Includes the option to specify the subject line.
  - The Body of the email can be written in the settings for the email.  No need to create a template email.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing @br-sayan . This is helpful from the next task I have.