# Redirect after submit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Can someone explain me how to make a simple redirect with the scripts used in google forms? The documentation seems very weird to me with the most things not working. I know how to set the event for when the submit is happening but how can i extend it with a redirect to a self-made "Thank you!" page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display custom message after submitting a Google Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644520/display-custom-message-after-submitting-a-google-form)

Comment: Please paste your code on your question.

Comment: You can **not** cause a new browser tab or browser window to open after submitting a Google Form.  And there is a good reason for that.  It would be a security problem.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I understand the security problem, but the form is running in an iframe, and I'd like to show a custom thanks page on this iframe, not on a new tab or browser. As I didnt mange to find such a solution already I guess thats also not possible, right? Thanks and have a great day! :)

Comment: @MaxMadman The best solution is to use a [Custom Sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) and install an [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) Trigger