# Does Google Forms have an on-screen alert function

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, alert, google-forms

Here's our problem, we have a Google form that when submitted; sends the inputs to a Google Sheet workbook. What we want is to have a system where if a survey participant has already submitted an entry for the week, we can get an on screen alert, not an email, to let us and the user know they already used their allotted participation for the week.

Is there a script or plugin that we can use.

Comment: Where do you want this alert to show up? In the spreadsheet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display custom message after submitting a Google Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644520/display-custom-message-after-submitting-a-google-form)