# Display image after submitting a Google Form

Tags: google-forms

I would like to ask if it is possible to display an image (either from an external source or from Google Drive of the same account as the form creator) as part of the confirmation message after a user has completed and submitted a Google Form.

I understand from the following past questions that there is no way to add dynamic data to the custom confirmation message after submitting a Google Form, but I am looking just to add an image:

1. [Display custom message after submitting a Google Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644520/display-custom-message-after-submitting-a-google-form)
2. [Is it possible to have a google form confirmation message that displays part of the response data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759942/is-it-possible-to-have-a-google-form-confirmation-message-that-displays-part-of)

Thank you!

Comment: you found any solutions?